# how to read a queries as a string from a file in java

Tags: java

I'm working on a project in java that use to compute similarity between a query and document, but the queries enter manually and I want to read it automatically because I have a lot of queries. I have used the following code in the main:

```
while(true) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter your query ");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        query = br.readLine();
        if (query.equals("ZZZ"))
            break;
        if (query.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("No query entered. Enter some query.");
            continue;
        }
        //lsiObj.handleQuery(query);
                    lsiObj.precision(query);
                   // lsiObj.ReadTD(TD);
    }
    System.out.println("\nThank you for trying out the system.");
}
```

thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @Thomas the problem is that I want to read queries automatically instead of manually. In the code above I enter the query each time and calculate the similarity and then enter the second query and so on.

Comment: In that case have a look at how to read files. It's not that different from your code, you'd just need an input stream on the file that containts the queries.

Comment: @nanije the official and free tutorial will answer all your questions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: @Thomas yes I see it , Thank you

Comment: @TimothyTruckle it's so helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to place all your queries in a text file, for ex. "queries.txt" file one per line and give it as input to the *BufferedReader*.

```
File queries = new File("queries.txt");
...
...
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(queries));
while((String line = br.readLine()) != null){
...do whatever you want
}
```